# MeteorJS conditional pub

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a MeteorJS project and I want to publish a certain set of users based on whether an `id` param is defined or not. When the `id` param has a value it gets a list of users perfectly, however, when it is null it returns nothing. I am using the `alanning:roles`package for user roles and the exact same query works fine in `meteor mongo`.

**Note:** I understand the implications of user pub and limiting fields. I just want to understand why the pub is returning nothing when the `id` is null.

```
// Server

Meteor.publish('userAccess', function(id) {
console.log(id); // null or array
if (!id || id == null) {
    return Meteor.users.find({
        'roles': {
            $in: ['admin', 'team']
        }
    });
} else {
    return Meteor.users.find({
        _id: id
    });     
}
});
```

Comment: As a quick tip, you can add the javascript tag to your question if you want the code highlight.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `alanning:roles` method and publish ids returned by it.

```
// Server

Meteor.publish('userAccess', function(id) {
console.log(id); // null or array
if (!id || id == null) {
    var Admins = Roles.getUsersInRole (['admin'])
    var Teams = Roles.getUsersInRole (['team'])
    // we intersect both array
    var adminsAndTeam = Admins.filter(function(n) {
         return Teams.indexOf(n) != -1;
    });
    return Meteor.users.find({
        _id: {
            $in: adminsAndTeam 
        }
    });
} else {
    return Meteor.users.find({
        _id: id
    });     
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically require that users belonging to both those roles be returned.

Comment: Not working. Getting this error in Terminal - `Exception from sub userAccess id FoLB7MCN6tN5EvhD2 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'filter'`

Answer (score 0):

The original code does work. The problem was in the front end where a conditional was in the wrong place and therefore not returning the users.